# How to change text color which is there in alert dialog's listview?

Tags: android, colors, android-alertdialog

Following is my code to display a simple Alert Dialog, when a button is clicked,

```
AlertDialog.Builder newImage = new AlertDialog.Builder( MyActivity.this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT );
newImage.setTitle( "Select Image" );
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (  MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 );
arrayAdapter.add( "Take from camera" );
arrayAdapter.add( "Select from gallery" );

newImage.setAdapter(arrayAdapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) 
    {
    }
});
```

This code, display output like below image,

> [image]

It shows list item in white color, that's why it is not visible. I want to change the list item's color to black.

What should I do for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (  MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ) {
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    text1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    return view;
  }
};
```

Simply override the getview of the `ArrayAdapter` and find the textView to change the color

Comment: It gives me this error, `06-12 09:58:03.367: E/AndroidRuntime(21225): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
06-12 09:58:03.367: E/AndroidRuntime(21225):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
06-12 09:58:03.367: E/AndroidRuntime(21225):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)`

Comment: are you talking about Custom AlertDialog ?

Comment: @user2060383 it is not custom. what it is doing is that it is overriding your getView to change the text color that's it.

Comment: Just an another question, Is it possible to give leftMarging to this textview programmatically ?

Comment: @user2060383 nope it is already bound to the view but you can change the padding.

Comment: I tried with `text1.setPadding ( 10,0,0,0 );` but it doesnt reflect

Comment: @user2060383 try to increase the left padding.. if it didnt work then maybe it is uneditable.

Comment: Ah, got it, it uses pixel rather than DP like we use in .xml :P

Comment: Is there any way to set the list item `textColor` by passing a theme to the `AlertDialog.Builder` constructor?

Comment: @bwicks I do not you can specify theme for the above example, what you do is to have a custom view instead for the list item

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView txt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
txt1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

**UPDATE**

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (  MyActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ) {
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    text1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    return view;
  }
};
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Nah, its not useful, its not even AlertDialog.

Comment: Where is the OP supposed to put the code? as it stands, this isn't an answer

Answer (score 1):

Just use your custom xml file for this instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and pass it to **ArrayAdapter.**

**Like this :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ff00ff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**And change adapter:**

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,R.layout.Your_xml,R.id.textView1);
```

Comment: @user2060383, may i know that whats the problem in using of your own layout instead of android.

Comment: Why to customized when you can do it natively ? But I like your answer too, thanks, +1

Answer (score 0):

you need to define custem alert Dialog view in layout like that 
first and then perform functionality

```
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(YourCurrentclass.this);
    View deleteDialogView = factory.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
    final AlertDialog deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            YourCurrentclass.this).create();
    deleteDialog.setView(deleteDialogView);
    final TextView text = (TextView) deleteDialogView
            .findViewById(R.id.textv2);
    Button p = (Button) deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.plusbtn);
    Button m = (Button) deleteDialogView.findViewById(R.id.minusbtn);
p.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    });
```

also you can change it from layout(mylayout) file when you create custom dilaoag like above in this .

Answer (score 0):

Use this easiest way to change text color :

Create String value into string.xml file in values folder like below

```
<string name="text1">Font color is <font fgcolor="#000000">Take from camera</font></string>
```

and you can use this string into adapter by this:

```
arrayAdapter.add(getResources().getString(R.string.text1));
```

hope this will work.Good luck..